# jQuery. Cloned element not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

I'm cloning some div by jQuery .clone(true) and inserting cloned element as last one, but then, when I'm trying to use selector :last for this element it's not working. Console do not show any error.
Here is how I clone element:

```
            $("div.addnewitem").on('click', function () {
                var $d = $("#example").clone(true);
                $($d).removeAttr("style");
                $($d).insertAfter("div.item:last");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("div.item:last").offset().top
                }, 2000);
            });
```

This is element to clone:

```
<div id="example" style="display: none;" class="item">
        <div class="deleteitem">
            <img alt="" src="../img/deleteitem.png">
        </div>
        <div class="itemphoto">
            <img alt="" src="../img/woolrich.png">
        </div>
        <div class="bigshadow">
            <img alt="" src="../img/bigshadow.png">
        </div>
        <div class="about">
            <input type="text" class="link" placeholder="Ссылка на изображение" name="item_image" />
            <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Вещь и бренд..." name="item_name">
            <textarea class="review" placeholder="Короткое описание (около 120 символов)..." name="item_desc"></textarea>
            <input type="text" class="link" placeholder="Ссылка на вещь..." name="item_url">
            <input type="text" class="pricestylist" placeholder="Цена (xxx руб/$)" name="item_price">
        </div>
    </div>
```

An here is the way how I want to manipulate cloned element:

```
$("input[name='item_url']:last").change(function (event) {
                if ($("#setname").val() != "") {
                    if ($("input[name='item_url']:last").val() != null) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '../ParseShop.asmx/ParseFott',
                            cache: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            data: "{'urlstring':'" + $("input[name='item_url']:last").val() + "'}",
                            success: function (msg) {
                                $("textarea[name='item_desc']:last").val($.trim(msg.d.ItemDescription));
                                $("input[name='item_name']:last").val($.trim(msg.d.ItemName));
                                $("input[name='item_price']:last").val($.trim(msg.d.ItemPrice));
                                $("input[name='item_image']:last").val($.trim(msg.d.ItemImageUrl));
                                $("img[id='itemimg']:last").attr('src', $.trim(msg.d.ItemImageUrl));
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                                alert(err.Message);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Вы забыли ввести ссылку на товар!");
                        $("input[name='item_url']:last").focus();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert("Вы забыли название комплекта!");
                    $("#setname").focus();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
```

P.S. Cloning function are working fine - I can clone and delete cloned elements, but why :last not working I do not have any idea.

Comment: You should be more specific where you are talking about. You are using :last all over the place. Do none of them work? Some? Which one(s)? What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Sorry, just this all is so clear for me )). It's not working here: $("input[name='item_url']:last").change(function (event) { }). <br /> All elements (original and cloned) has same 'name' attribute so I'm using its as selector.

Comment: What do you mean not working? The :last is pretty much useless there anyway since that element is the only one with that name within its parent.

Comment: Maybe you are meaning to do something like $("div.item:last input[name='item_url']");

Comment: Unfortunately, there is something else.

Comment: When do you assign `.change` listener - before cloning or after it?

Comment: It may be different user behavior but mostly user .change() first, then .clone()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is the solution that working for me.

```
$("div.item").on('change', 'input[name="item_url"]', function (event) {
                if ($("#setname").val() != "") {
                    if ($(this).val() != null) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '../ParseShop.asmx/ParseFott',
                            cache: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            data: "{'urlstring':'" + $("input[name='item_url']:last").val() + "'}",
                            success: function (msg) {
                                $("div.item:last textarea[name='item_desc']").val($.trim(msg.d.ItemDescription));
                                $("div.item:last input[name='item_name']").val($.trim(msg.d.ItemName));
                                $("div.item:last input[name='item_price']").val($.trim(msg.d.ItemPrice));
                                $("div.item:last input[name='item_image']").val($.trim(msg.d.ItemImageUrl));
                                $("div.item:last img[id='itemimg']").attr('src', $.trim(msg.d.ItemImageUrl));
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                                alert(err.Message);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Вы забыли ввести ссылку на товар!");
                        $("input[name='item_url']:last").focus();
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert("Вы забыли название комплекта!");
                    $("#setname").focus();
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

P.S. Based on Brian answer. Brian, you may add your comment as answer.